# How to get my table where my session data stored

Tags: session

i have stored my data in my magento database using

```
<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

my question is that **in which table my data store in my database**.

Answer (score 8):

Session data will be stored in the **core_session** table with `session ID, session expire and session file`.